# Iterating over all edges in a graph yields different time complexities

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

A quite simple question regarding time complexity: Let $G = (V,E)$ be a directed Graph. Suppose I want to iterate over all Edges $e \in E(G)$.

One way would be:
**for** $e \in E(G)$ **do**
$\qquad$ **output** $e$
**end for**
This has obviously a runtime of $\mathcal O(|E(G)|)$.

Another way would be:
**for** $v \in V(G)$ **do**
$\qquad$ **for** $e \in \delta^+(v)$ **do**
$\qquad\qquad$ **output** $e$
$\qquad$ **end for**
**end for**
But this has runtime $\mathcal O(|V(G)| + |E(G)|)$, since we will definitely encounter every edge, but also every vertex in the outer loop. This becomes very prominent for sparse graphs, e.g. an empty graph with no edges.

And there are probably many more ways to do the *same* thing, *iterating over all edges*.

**What would be the "correct" runtime in any algorithm that iterates over edges?**
I know that the above problem boils down to data structures (list vs. incidence list), but what do e.g. authors in papers assume for their complexity analysis?

Comment: I think you have to read the paper and infer which data structure they're assuming is given. Often it won't matter, though, because converting from one data structure to the other is faster than the algorithm being studied (so we can assume the conversion is done in advance).

Comment: It is very rare that one has to carefully consider graphs where almost all vertices are isolated, which is what you'd need for $\mathcal O(|V(G)| + |E(G)|)$ to be worse than $\mathcal O(|E(G)|)$. Usually when I look at an algorithm I think about what it does in the "sparse" case where $|E(G)| = \Theta(|V(G)|)$ and the "dense" case where $|E(G)| = \Theta(|V(G)|^2)$.